# Bootstrap 5 collapse using width not transitioning from hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to use the BS5 collapse component, but using width instead of height.

I modified my element `.collapsing` to use width instead of height:

```
#sidebar {
    width: 15rem;
}

#sidebar.collapsing {
    width: 0;
    height: auto;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}
```

This works great for when the element is being hidden. It shows a smooth hiding animation. However, when showing the element, there is no animation at all.

Here is a fiddle with complete code example:

https://jsfiddle.net/v72p0azg/

Click the hamburger icon to expand/collapse the sidebar. As you can see, on collapsing it works perfectly, but on expanding it shows with no transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to add transition to the plain #sidebar as well.

Try this.

```
 #sidebar {
    width: 15rem;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
}

#sidebar.collapsing {
    width: 0;
    height: auto;
    transition: width 0.35s ease;
    }
```